# jre and jdk installation

Tags: jdk, jre

I got following error while installing the open jdk from ubuntu 14.04.
how do i solve this ?

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (>= 7~u3-2.1.1)
 openjdk-6-jre-lib : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b27)
 openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: What is the command you are running?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run below command so it will install dependencies of java.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```